# Oracle/SQL - Need help optimizing COUNT DISTINCT query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, query-optimization, distinct

I am running Oracle 10g. This below query as it is takes about 25 min to run.
I looked at the execution plan and from what I can tell about 80% of the cost is the `DISTINCT COUNT`.

```
SELECT STG.dts_start_dt_wid, 
   ML.sales_org_wid, 
   ML.cost_center_wid, 
   ML.chnl_type_wid, 
   ML.x_generic_lead_source_wid, 
   ML.x_specific_lead_source_wid, 
   ML.x_order_category_wid, 
   Count(DISTINCT ML.row_wid) AS TOTAL_ACTIVE_LICENSES 
FROM   wc_lsp_master_license_d ML, 
   wc_reflex_daily_activity_a_stg STG 
WHERE  ML.license_class = 'REFLEX' 
   AND STG.dts_start_dt_wid BETWEEN ML.extensions_start_dt_wid AND 
                                    ML.extensions_end_dt_wid 
   AND ML.license_name NOT LIKE '%demo@rosettastone.com' 
GROUP  BY STG.dts_start_dt_wid, 
      ML.sales_org_wid, 
      ML.cost_center_wid, 
      ML.chnl_type_wid, 
      ML.x_generic_lead_source_wid, 
      ML.x_specific_lead_source_wid, 
      ML.x_order_category_wid;
```

Unfortunately, I need to get a count of distinct row_wids. So I am trying to figure out if there is anything I can do to make the first query run faster.

Here is a screenshot of the execution plan :

[image]

Any help or feedback on this would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: . . There is really no join condition between the tables that refers to something like the license?

Comment: 1. run `alter session set statistics_level = all;` 2. run your query in the same session 3. after the query is finished run `SELECT t.*
FROM v$sql s, table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR(s.sql_id, s.child_number, 'ALLSTATS LAST')) t WHERE upper(sql_text) LIKE upper('%Count(DISTINCT ML.row_wid) AS TOTAL_ACTIVE_LICENSES%');` and post output here

Comment: Gordon Linoff,Thank u for ur reply.

Comment: Could you please post your table create statements and the keys? @Sbejavada

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, verify that the columns you use in your WHERE clauses (and from the COUNT DISTINCT) have indexes (or are primary/unique/foreign keys).

Secondly, check if you could add other WHERE clauses to replace the DISTINCT in the COUNT, or even replace it with a COUNT(*) which is very optimized.

Thirdly, you could try to move your count(distinct) to another join or even a subquery and check if performances changes.

Answer (score 0):

If a sort group by operation is taking a high cost, it is likely to be due to the sort spilling to disk. You can check this with [V$SQL_WORKAREA_ACTIVE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2127.htm) while the query is running.

Note the MAX_MEM_USED, the NUMBER_OF_PASSES, and the TEMPSEG_SIZE.

If the number of passes is greater than 1 then you have multipass sort, which is a very slow operation. One pass is not too bad, but note how large a temporary segment the query needs as that determines how much i/o is used during the sort operation.

This fixes for this are either:

1. Increase your memory allocation for sorts, either for the instance as a whole or for your session in particular, or ...
2. Reduce the amount of data you are sorting. Primarily this means to reduce the key size for the sort, which you can sometimes do when you have elements in the group by that are dependent on other elements. You can group by only the required elements and then join to that result set to get the other dependent elements.
3. Use parallel query.